# Pointers in Assembly

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

I'm having trouble with a practice problem from my textbook.
I have to fill in the missing parts of the C code shown below:

```
int switch3(int *p1, int *p2, int action)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch(action) {
    case 1:
     // Fill in
    case 2:
     // Fill in
    default:
     // Fill in
}
     return result;
}
```

The reason I'm having trouble is because of the use of pointers. I'm pretty sure I know how they work, but let me elaborate. 
The book gives us the following IA32 assembly with my annotations in comments.

```
Arguments: p1 at %ebp+8, p2 at %ebp+12, action at %ebp+16
 Registers: result in %edx (initialized to -1) The jump targets:

.L13 // case(1)
  movl  8(%ebp), %eax // eax = p1
  movl  (%eax), %edx  // result = *p1
  movl  12(%ebp), %ecx // ecx = p2
  movl  (%ecx), %eax   // eax = *p2
  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx  // ecx = p1 
  movl %eax, (%ecx)   // *p1 = *p2
```

So at the end, it is result = *p1 and
                     *p1 = *p2
I think this is correct, but what's next is what's confusing me.

```
.L14 //case(2)
   movl  12(%ebp), %edx // result = p2  which is not possible because p2 is a pointer and result is an int
   movl  (%edx), %eax  
  movl   %eax, %edx
  movl    8(%ebp), %ecx
  addl (%ecx), %edx
  movl  12(%ebp), %eax
  movl  %edx, (%eax)
  jmp  .L19

 .L19 // default
    movl %edx, %eax
```

Could anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: Think if `edx` as `int * q`. So you have `int * q = p2; result = *q;`.

Comment: But how is this posible if result is an int and the instructions tell us that "result in %edx"? Does this mean that edx will be returned in the end and you assume that it will be the final result variable?

Comment: You need to show some of the "more instructions".  `edx` gets loaded with a pointer, true, but then it gets dereferenced into `eax`.

Comment: Ok, added the full instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.L14 //case(2)
  movl  12(%ebp), %edx // result = p2  which is not possible because 
                       // p2 is a pointer and result is an int
```

Your comment `result = p2` is wrong. `edx` is NOT tied to `result` for the entire duration of the function. The only thing you know is that right after the function exits, `result` is stored in `edx`. 
(Furthermore, even though not directly relevant to your question, assembly has no concept of types beyond their sizes, so a register doesn't know whether it holds a pointer or an int.)

So:

```
.L14 //case(2)
  movl  12(%ebp), %edx   // edx = p2
  movl  (%edx), %eax     // eax = *p2
  movl   %eax, %edx      // edx = eax ( = *p2 )
  movl    8(%ebp), %ecx  // ecx = p1
  addl (%ecx), %edx      // edx = edx + *p1 ( = *p1 + *p2 )
  movl  12(%ebp), %eax   // eax = p2
  movl  %edx, (%eax)     // *p2 = edx ( = *p1 + *p2 )
  jmp  .L19              // if .L19 is the end of the function, then you now know
                         // that result = *p1 + *p2
```

Comment: So, for case 2 it should be: case 2: result = *p1 + *p2;  *p2 = result; break; @us2012