# How to interpret this IA32 assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

As an assignment, I must read the assembly code and write its high-level C program. The structure in this case is a `switch` statement, so for each case, the assembly code is translated to the case in C code. Below will only be one of the cases. If you can help me interpret this, it should give me a better understanding of the rest of the cases.

```
p1 is in %ebp+8
p2 is in %ebp+12
action is in %ebp+16
result is in %edx

...
.L13:
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax    # get p1
    movl (%eax), %edx     # result = *p1?
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx   # get p2
    movl (%ecx), %eax     # p1 = *p2
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx    # p2 = p1
    movl %eax, (%ecx)     # *p1 = *p2?
    jmp .L19              #jump to default
...
.L19
    movl %edx, %eax       # set return value
```

Of course, the comments were added by me to try to make sense of it, except it leaves me more confused. Is this meant to be a swap? Probably not; the formatting would be different. What really happens in the 2nd and 6th lines? Why is %edx only changed once so early if it's the return value? Please answer with some guidelines to interpreting this code.

Comment: You *do* know that the order of operands in reversed in AT&T syntax? So the last statement is `MOV EAX,EDX` not the other way round.

Comment: @CarlNorum it wasn't me...

Comment: @Johan Every line in this example is written verbatim from the textbook

Comment: That's cool, I do understand, but your statement that this is a switch statement is incorrect.  A switch statement would involve `test` or `cmp` and conditional jumps, not pointer manipulation.

Comment: Line for line identical to [Pointers in Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284338/pointers-in-assembly) down to the name of the compile-generated temporary label. Don't forget to mention in your assignment that you got help from the internet, otherwise you are guilty of academic dishonesty.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Relax, September is here to stay. I feel you're rather harsh on the newbie.

Comment: @Johan Remember when newbies understood what a web site was for before posting? The site is for helping others with the same problem. So look to see if somebody already solved your problem. (I should probably give up on academic honesty. Cheating is normal nowadays I guess.)

Answer (score 4):

The above snippet is x86_32 assembly in the (IMO broken) AT&T syntax.

AT&T syntax attaches a size suffix to every operand.

`movl` means a 32 bit operand.  (l for long)
`movw` means 16 bit operand     (w for word)
`movb` means an 8 bit operand  (b for byte)

The operands are reversed in order, so the destination is on the right and the source is on the left.
This is opposite to almost every other programming language.

Register names are prefixed by a `%` to distinguish them from variable names. 
If a register is surrounded by brackets `()` that means that the memory address pointed to by the register is used, rather than the value inside the register itself.
This makes sense, because EBP is used as a pointer to a stackframe.
Stackframes are used to access parameters and local variables in functions.

Instead of writing: `mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]` *(Intel syntax)*
AT&T syntax lists it as: `movl 8(%ebp), %eax` *[(gas syntax)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler)*

Which means: put the contends of the memory address pointed to by (ebp + 8) into eax.

Here's the translation:

```
.L13:   <<-- label used as a jump target. 
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax    <<--  p1, stored at ebp+8 goes into EAX
    movl (%eax), %edx     <<-- p1 is a pointer, EDX = p1->next
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx   <<-- p2, stored at ebp+12 goes in ECX
    movl (%ecx), %eax     <<-- p2 is (again) a pointer, EAX = p2->next
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx    <<-- ECX = p1
    movl %eax, (%ecx)     <<-- p2->next = p1->next 
    jmp .L19              <<-- jump to exit 
...
.L19
    movl %edx, %eax       <<-- EAX is always the return value
                          <<-- return p1->data.
```

In all of the many calling conventions on x86 the return value of a function is put into the EAX register. (or EAX:EDX if it's an INT64)

In prose: p1 and p2 are pointers to data, in this data pointers to pointers.
This code looks like it manipulates a linked list.
`p2->next` is set to `p1->next`.
Other than that the snippet looks incomplete because whatever was in `p2->next` to begin with is not worked on so there probably more code that you're not showing.

Apart from the confusing AT&T syntax it's really very simple code.

In C the code would look like:

```
(void *)p2->next = (void *)p1->next;
```

Note that the code is quite inefficient and no decent compiler (or human) would generate this code.

The following equivalent would make more sense:

```
mov eax,[ebp+8]
mov ecx,[ebp+12]
mov eax,[eax]
mov [ecx],eax
jmp done
```

More info on the difference between AT&T and Intel syntax can be found here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your comments look very similar to my comments, so I had the right idea. By subsitiuting "*p1" to "p1->next", I think I can better understand this case and the subsequent cases.

Comment: Yes you where pretty close, of course reversing source and destination put you off. Other than that you had it nailed.