# C Pointers & AT&T Movl Syntax

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, att

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two commands in AT&T assembly language.

```
movl    %edx, %eax
movl    (%ebx), %eax
```

I understand that the first command takes the value in %edx and puts that value in %eax.
My understanding is that the second one is ...something... to do with pointers. But wouldn't %ebx be the address and whatever value it contains be the value at that address?

I've looked a lot of different tutorials, wiki articles, powerpoints, and stack overflow posts, but I can't find anyone that's clearly explained it. The best I've seen is at http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/04fa/notes/l2.pdf.

They give the example

```
movl    %edx, %eax    //edx = eax
movl    (%ebx), %eax  //edx = *((int32_t*) ebx)
```

Which confirms I was right about the first, but the second they are typecasting ebx as a pointer or..? It's part of an assignment for class which I accidentally came across the answer while searching for existing questions. The assignment is almost identical to [C, Assembly : understanding the switch condition, edx eax ecx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624330/c-assembly-understanding-the-switch-condition-edx-eax-ecx) and [Pointers in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284338/pointers-in-assembly), but honestly I didn't read those because I don't want to learn what the answers are from the posts, I want to learn how to do it and check my work against them.

Thanks if you can help!!

Comment: In the second case ebx is treated as an address. in `C` it would be `int32_t *ebx;  *ebx = eax`

Comment: Two things to remember: There are no "types" in assembler the same way there is in C. The second thing is that a pointer is something whose value is an address to the pointed to value. And if you don't really understand what the syntax `(%ebx)` really means, you need to learn assembly better first.

Comment: @BuellaGábor would that really be *ebx = eax? Isn't eax the value being set?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I concur I really need to learn assembly better. That's what this class I'm taking is, and that's why I'm posting here for additional help :)

Comment: @ElliottPost I don't use assembly generally, so I don't remember which syntax has what order and so on. Anyways, the point is, `(%ebx)` means addressing the memory, so if `%ebx == 76` then `(%ebx)` means get/set the value at address `76` in RAM

Comment: But I develop in `C` probably you should tag the question as `assembly` , so some assembly people will come here to help you out

Comment: Thanks Buella. I improved the tag based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax

The ATT syntax uses source before destination, so

```
movl %edx, %eax
```

is equivalent to

```
eax = edx
```

The more complicated example

```
movl (%ebx), %eax
```

is equivalent to

```
eax = *((int32 *) ebx;
```

The reason for the `int32` is that the instruction has the letter `l` at the end (that's a lower case L). Different letters specify different types, but `l` specifies a signed 32-bit number.  The parentheses around `(%ebx)` indicate that an effective address is being specified.  An effective address has only one mandatory element (the `BASE` address), and 3 optional elements.  In your example, only the mandatory base address is supplied.  When given an instruction with an effective address, the address is computed as follows

```
address = base + index * scale + displacement
```

In the C version of the statement, casting ebx to an `(int32 *)` converts the value in `ebx` to a pointer that points to an `int32` at the effective address, and then dereferencing that pointer reads the 32-bit number at that address.

Comment: A generic question to check my understanding:
if ebx = 0x00FF, then movl (%ebx), %eax, finds the value at memory location 0x00FF and puts that into %eax? Thus, the effective address, in this example, is 0x00FF?

Comment: Yup, that's right. The byte at 0x00ff goes into the lowest 8-bits of %eax. The byte at 0x0100 goes into the second lowest 8-bits of %eax, and so on for four bytes.